# Realm crash with the error reason: 'Property 'person' is declared as 'NSArray' even though I have removed the array

Tags: swift, realm

I'm new to Realm and I have tried to save an object with an array inside however I got a crash and after reading the error it turned out that Realm does not accept arrays so I removed the array but I still get an error whenever I use realm. Here is one sample code which gets the Error :

```
let realm = RealmService.shared.realm
    print(realm.objects(Person))
```

and here is the full error :

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Property 'person' is declared as 'NSArray', which is not a supported RLMObject property type. All properties must be primitives, NSString, NSDate, NSData, NSNumber, RLMArray, RLMLinkingObjects, or subclasses of RLMObject
```

and here is RealmService class :

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class RealmService{


private init(){}

static let shared = RealmService()

var realm = try! Realm()

func create<T: Object>(_ object: T){
    do{
        try realm.write {
            realm.add(object)
        }
    }catch{
        post(error)
    }
}

func update<T: Object>(_ object: T, with dictionary: [String: Any?]){
    do{
        try realm.write {
            for (key,value) in dictionary{
                object.setValue(value, forKey: key)
            }
        }
    }catch{
        post(error)
    }
}

func delete<T: Object>(_ object: T ){
    do{
        try realm.write {
            realm.delete(object) 
        }
    }catch{
        post(error)
    }
}

func post(_ error: Error){
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("RealmError"), object: error)
}

func observeRealmErrors(in vc: UIViewController, completion: @escaping (Error?)-> Void){
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name("RealmError"), object: nil, queue:  nil) { (notification) in
        completion(notification.object as? Error)
    }
}

func stopObserving(in vc: UIViewController){
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(vc, name: NSNotification.Name("RealmError"), object: nil)
}
}
```

**Update :**

Person class :

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class Person: Object{
@objc dynamic var name: String = ""
@objc dynamic var id: String = ""
@objc dynamic var phone: String = ""
@objc dynamic var country : String = ""
@objc dynamic var identifier: String = ""
@objc dynamic var gender : Int = 0
@objc dynamic var level: Int = 0
@objc dynamic var mena: Int = 0
@objc dynamic var moz: Int = 0
@objc dynamic var arafat: Int = 0
@objc dynamic var group: NSNumber = 0

convenience init(group: NSNumber, name: String, id: String, phone: String, country: String, identifier: String, gender: Int, level: Int) {
    self.init()
    self.name = name
    self.phone = phone
    self.id = id
    self.country = country
    self.identifier = identifier
    self.gender = gender
    self.level = level
    self.group = group
}
}
```

Comment: Can you show the `Object` subclass that is causing the problem?

Comment: @Sweeper I have updated the question , by the way as I said earlier the class Person had an array and I have removed that array after I faced this error

Comment: Try cleaning the project and building it again. If that didn't work, uninstall the app on the simulator and reinstall it again.

Comment: @Sweeper I'm working on a real device , tried cleaning the project and tried uninstalling the app same problem

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to be a realm problem, but more of an xCode one.

1. Super clean the project `cmd + alt + shft + k`.
2. Delete derived data in `/Users/signed-in-user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`
3. Delete the application from your device to clear all realm data (changing a model will require either wiping the app or migrating the database)
4. Restart xcode and see if that helps. (completely quit it)

This often fixes a number of issues including phantom break points. I had one very odd problem once that caused data to exist in the realm file, but when accessed in code, it didn't exist. After testing on a coworker's computer I found it to be my xCode. Even the above did not fix the problem and after trying everything you can find online, I re-installed after a full wipe of the previous install and it worked again.

Also, use lists for realm

```
`let emailList = List<String>()`
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I switched to sqlite